# Simple Microsoft demo wcf service works on classic authentication web app, but fails on a claims based web app. Why?

Tags: claims-based-auth, wcf

This must be something very simple I just don't get.

I create the demo wcf service by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx

I create two web applications on my SP2010 development farm, one with Claims, one with Classic. I add a site collection to both.

Next I deploy the simple demo service to both. And try to call it from visual studio console application.

I add the following line to on the client (in order to use Ntlm authentication)

using (MyClient client = new MyClient())
{
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = 
System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
}

This works for the classic web application but gives the following error on the claims web application:
"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'."

Answer (score 1):

If your web application is configured for Claims mode authentication, then you cannot pass NTLM credentials/tokens. You must get a FedAuth token from the identity provider and pass it to the service.

I suggest that you read Vittorio's book on Windows Identity Framework programming.http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-Identity-Foundation-Dev/dp/0735627185

Comment: Actually funny thing it just started to work.

Comment: ...after switching to SP oob web.config instead of a custom one.

Comment: ..i mean the service seems to work with windows cretentials: i can recognize the user in the service, and personalize based on the current user. but do you mean there's something wrong in this approach?

Comment: Can you explain the statement "If your web application is configured for Claims mode authentication, then you cannot pass NTLM credentials/tokens. You must get a FedAuth token from the identity provider and pass it to the service." with a example.

Comment: I will not. Read up on Microsoft's support of claims identity and you will find a wealth of information.